# IntelliJ IDEA how to remove space after exclamation mark

Tags: java, xcode, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 (Ultimate Edition). I tried to remove the space after ! but was not successful. Preference->Code Style->Spaces. How can I remove the space after ! . Thanks

```
    if (! isTrue) {//I do not want the space after ! mark(before is isTrue)

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preference->Code Style->Spaces> Around Operators > **Uncheck Unary Operators.**

save , and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to see the effect.

[image]